# asp.net modelbinding into complex types

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-binding

I'm trying to simplify some of my code.

I have a view that returns data,

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href='@Url.Action("DownloadXls", "ArchivedMessages", new
                            {
                                Locations = string.Join(",", Model.SelectedLocations),
                                Machines = string.Join(",", Model.SelectedMachines),
                                Severities = string.Join(",", Model.SelectedSeverities),
                                Messages = string.Join(",", Model.SelectedMessages),
                                FromDate = Model.FromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                ToDate = Model.ToDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                GroupMachines = Model.GroupMachines,
                                GroupMessages = Model.GroupMessages
                            })'>
    @Resources.ExportData
</a>
```

This calls the following method in my controller

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadXls(List<int> Locations, List<int> Machines, List<int> Severities, List<int> Messages,
        bool GroupMachines, bool GroupMessages, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
    {
        var reportData = await mediator.Send(new ArchivedMessagesExcelQuery
        {
            Locations = Locations,
            Machines = Machines,
            Severities = Severities,
            Messages = Messages,
            FromDate = FromDate,
            ToDate = ToDate,
            GroupMachines = GroupMachines,
            GroupMessages = GroupMessages
        });

        return File(reportData, "application/vnd.ms-excel", $"{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}-data_export.xlsx");
    }
```

Now what i would like to do is simplify all this. Since the data goes straight into an object initializer.

something like this which i know is possible in ASP.net

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadXls(ArchivedMessagesExcelQuery query)
{
    var reportData = await mediator.Send(query);
    return File(reportData, "application/vnd.ms-excel", $"{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}-data_export.xlsx");
}
```

unfortunatly the 4 List vallues remain null after i change this.

these values get set trough a modelbinder

```
public class IntArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value == null) return new List<int>();

        var attempted = value.AttemptedValue;
        return attempted.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
    }
}
```

But creating a modelbinder per querytype would give me more code then it saves.

Is there a way to apply this modelbinder to all string to List cases even if they are inside complex types?

Comment: Why don't you create a class to wrap all the data?

Comment: Your view model already seems to have all the properties you need. Wrap your view in a form and post that to the controller.